# Figure out array length statically using templates in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I'm looking to write a char buf wrapper that guarantees null-termination like the following:

```
template<size_t N> class BufStr
{
public:
    explicit BufStr(const char(&buf)[N])
    {
        memcpy(m_buf, buf, N);
        m_buf[N-1] = '\0';
    }

    inline const char* c_str() const { return m_buf; }

protected:
    char m_buf[N];
};
```

But I'd like to use the signature template and be able to pass in a char buf directly to the constructor which would be able to determine the size of array using sizeof therefore computing N at compile time.

Comment: If you said `MakeBufStr("Hello")`, that would already contain a null terminator, right?

Comment: this is a function to convert a non-null terminated char buf like char buf[10] into a null terminated

Comment: Of course, the standard "class template plus deducing make function" idiom. You just got an answer explaining that.

Comment: I see, I was wondering if there was a way to do it all in one templated class.

Comment: No, because you can't pick a member function *until* you've specified the class!

Comment: Should this account for a potential short-buffer due to actual termination? I.e. if `char buff[10]` actually *has* a terminator at, say, slot 5, should the resulting string be no longer than 5 chars (4+1) ? And if it doesn't, then a buffer with 11 chars (10+1) ? Or did you give that any consideration at all?

Answer (score 2):

**Edited** To account for the fact that you want to 'wrap' non-zero-terminated char arrays:

You could have a 'factory' function:

```
template <size_t N> 
   BufStr<N+1> make_bufstr(const char(&buf)[N])
{
    return BufStr<N+1>(buf);
}
```

Demo (note the use of `std::copy` instead of `memcpy`):

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <algorithm>

template<std::size_t N> class BufStr
{
public:
    explicit BufStr(const char(&buf)[N-1])
    {
        static_assert(N>0, "illegal size");
        std::copy(buf, buf+N-1, m_buf);
        m_buf[N-1] = '\0';
    }

    inline const char* c_str() const { return m_buf; }

protected:
    char m_buf[N];
};

template <size_t N> 
   BufStr<N+1> make_bufstr(const char(&buf)[N])
{
    return BufStr<N+1>(buf);
}

int main()
{
    const char raw[] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' }; // no NUL termination!
    auto s = make_bufstr(raw); // adds terminating NUL
}
```

Comment: Ah, I misread and didn't realize that this was the stumbling point. Yeah, the "Hello world" example seems to be exactly *not* what's wanted.

Comment: Grand. I'm still unsure if such a function would be useful, at all. Much better to say `std::string(std::begin(raw), std::end(raw)` and get the exact same functionality.

Comment: I know right. He's asking about how to provision a system like that, using his own class template though.

Comment: @user1095108 maybe. There's little use since `BufStr`'s constructor cannot be made `constexpr` anyways.

Comment: @user1095108 What are you doing? You know that that would change precisely nothing in practice, right? It's a _function template_ anyways

Comment: function templates are not automatically `inline`d. Look for it on SO, but never mind.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
template <typename T>
using buf_type = BufStr<::std::extent<T, 0>{}>;

int main()
{
  char bla[] = "heh";

  buf_type<decltype(bla)> buf(bla);

  return 0;
}
```